# How to trigger browser click event in browser and send event to C# host app

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension

There are tab open, tab close, tab update events, that we can send the events to host app. Is it possible to sent the click events that we click in the browser to the c# host app?

Comment: You should be able to forward any events that you can listen to via nativeMessaging https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: To process DOM events use a content script with a `mousedown` listener and normal messaging to the background script, which can relay it via nativeMessaging.

Comment: @GergelySzabo my application is listening to each other via native messaging. I have to send the events from C# application to chrome. how could that possible.

Comment: @user11738472 I think the extension has to initiate the connection.

Comment: i had tried using the named pipe stream and natiive messaging but once the pipe breaks difficult to reconnect